# Does race choice really matter in Illyriad?

Tags: illyriad

Does race choice really matter in Illyriad?  It seems like all the races have more or less the same unit types, and they all have the same buildings.  Is there a race bonus that I'm missing somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the sign up info (click the [i] on register pages):
http://uk1.illyriad.co.uk/view_player_registration.asp

**Races**

There are 4 player races in Illyriad, each with their own strengths and weaknesses.

New players are advised that Humans are probably the easiest all-round race to play; with the most balanced military, diplomatic, trade and magic capabilities.

**Humans**

Humans are probably the most evenly balanced of the races. They are not imbued with superlative strengths or weaknesses in offence, defense or magic. They do, however, have a rich cultural history of trade and diplomatic machinations. Detractors might call it cunning or guile - and humans certainly excel in these areas.

Humans are a great choice of race for a new player to Illyriad, starting with 5 wood, 5 clay, 5 iron, 5 stone and 5 food city plots to exploit.

**Elves**

Elves have a long relationship with the arcane mysteries of Illyriad, and as such make the best magic users of all the races.

Although by no means defenceless, Elves are one of Illyriad's more difficult races to play well as it can take valuable time to get an Elven city to a necessary level of magical proficiency.

Elves start their first city with 7 wood, 3 clay, 5 iron, 5 stone and 5 food city plots to exploit.

**Dwarves**

Dwarves are the master manipulators of stone. Their city buildings are legendarily secure, and they can also muster sturdy swordsmen.

Dwarves are a strong choice for those who want to rely on their defensive game, and dwarven cities start with 5 wood, 5 clay, 7 stone, 3 iron and 5 food city plots to exploit.

**Orcs**

Orcs see themselves as the rightful ruling race in Illyriad, but will deal with the other races quite happily - so long as it is to their advantage to do so.

Fierce, strong and brave in numbers, Orcs excel in waging an offensive playstyle by using their Goblin and Kobold minions as wall fodder as they wreak havoc across the land.

Orcs start with 3 wood, 7 clay, 5 stone, 5 iron and 5 food city plots to exploit.

Comment: Also there was a discussion this very topic in the forums:
http://forum.illyriad.co.uk/races_topic1442.html
But everyone seemed to have their own opinion...